# Remove the ability to click outside of the divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu which consists of a set of Divs and in order for the user to choose one choice from the others on this menu he has to click on the div but there is a problem which is that the user can click outside the div to select the choice (if you move horizontally from each div you will see the ability to click) which i don't want. I have tried to specify the width for the a tag in order to make it the width of the div but it didn't work. I tried adjusting the width of the div to see what is problem but couldn't solve.
Here are the codes for this menu:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(".page2").hide();
 $("#back").hide();
 $("#next").click(function () {
  $(".items").hide();
  $(".page2").css({"width": "50%", "height": "50px","background-color": "#2f8073", "border-radius": "5px", "border": "1px ridge #1c1c1c", "margin-bottom": "15px"});
  $(".page2").show();
  $("#next").hide();
  $("#back").show();
 });
 $("#back").click(function () {
  $(".page2").hide();
  $(".items").show();
  $("#back").hide();
  $("#next").show();
 });
 $(".page2").hover(function() {
  $(this).css({"background-color": "#2f8073", "border-radius": "5px", "border": "1px ridge #1c1c1c", "margin-bottom": "15px", "height" : "52px", "width" : "52%"});
 }, function() {
  $(this).css({"width": "50%", "height": "50px","background-color": "#2f8073", "border-radius": "5px", "border": "1px ridge #1c1c1c", "margin-bottom": "15px"});
 });

});
```

```css
.items {
 width: 50%;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: #2f8073;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 1px ridge #1c1c1c;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.page2 {
 width: 50%;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: #2f8073;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 1px ridge #1c1c1c;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
}

h1 {
 font-size: 23px;
 color: black;
 font: arial;

}
a {
 text-decoration: none;
}
.items:hover, .page2:hover {
  width: 52%;
 height: 52px;
}
.items, .page2 {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
 <title>Menu</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<a href="index.html">
<div style="margin-top:10px;"class="items">
<h1><b>Choice 1</b></h1>
</div>
</a>
<a href="index.html">
<div class="items">
<h1><b>Choice 2</b></h1>
</div>
</a>
<a href="index.html">
<div class="items">
<h1><b>Choice 3</b></h1>
</div>
</a>
<a href="index.html">
<div class="items">
<h1><b>Choice 4</b></h1>
</div>
</a>
<a href="index.html">
<div class="items">
<h1><b>Choice 5</b></h1>
</div>
</a>
<a href="index.html">
<div style="margin-top:10px;" class="page2">
<h1><b>Choice 6</b></h1>
</div>
</a>
</center>
</div>
<img id="next" style="margin-top: 8px; height: 60px; position: relative; left: 48%" src="http://i.imgur.com/yse3cEr.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://i.imgur.com/nDvQje1.png'" onmouseout="this.src='http://i.imgur.com/yse3cEr.png'">
<img id="back" style="margin-top: 35px; height: 69px; position: relative; left: 48%; bottom: 1.7em" src="http://i.imgur.com/TVVVUju.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://i.imgur.com/lHpV00R.png'" onmouseout="this.src='http://i.imgur.com/TVVVUju.png'">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would suggest giving the <a> tag a class, edit the css of the class to basically be the same as the div define the height and width and remove the extra divs with class "items"

Comment: Not to nitpick, but `<center>` isn't html5, and from what I can see this could all be done in just css without the js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest giving the `<a>` tag a class, edit the css of the class to basically be the same as the div define the height and width and remove the extra divs with class "items" as they are redundant

example here just adding the css you applied to the divs to the `<a>` tag and removing the divs

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".page2").hide();
  $("#back").hide();
  $("#next").click(function() {
    $(".items").hide();
    $(".page2").css({
      "width": "50%",
      "height": "50px",
      "background-color": "#2f8073",
      "border-radius": "5px",
      "border": "1px ridge #1c1c1c",
      "margin-bottom": "15px"
    });
    $(".page2").show();
    $("#next").hide();
    $("#back").show();
  });
  $("#back").click(function() {
    $(".page2").hide();
    $(".items").show();
    $("#back").hide();
    $("#next").show();
  });
  $(".page2").hover(function() {
    $(this).css({
      "background-color": "#2f8073",
      "border-radius": "5px",
      "border": "1px ridge #1c1c1c",
      "margin-bottom": "15px",
      "height": "52px",
      "width": "52%"
    });
  }, function() {
    $(this).css({
      "width": "50%",
      "height": "50px",
      "background-color": "#2f8073",
      "border-radius": "5px",
      "border": "1px ridge #1c1c1c",
      "margin-bottom": "15px"
    });
  });

});
```

```css
.items {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #2f8073;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px ridge #1c1c1c;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.page2 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #2f8073;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px ridge #1c1c1c;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 23px;
  color: black;
  font: arial;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.items:hover,
.page2:hover {
  width: 52%;
  height: 52px;
}
.items,
.page2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
  <title>Menu</title>
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <a href="index.html" class="items" style="margin-top:10px;">
      <h1><b>Choice 1</b></h1>
    </a>
    <a href="index.html" class="items" style="margin-top:10px;">
      <h1><b>Choice 2</b></h1>
    </a>
    <a href="index.html" class="items" style="margin-top:10px;">
      <h1><b>Choice 3</b></h1>
    </a>
    <a href="index.html" class="items" style="margin-top:10px;">
      <h1><b>Choice 4</b></h1>
    </a>
    <a href="index.html" class="items" style="margin-top:10px;">
      <h1><b>Choice 5</b></h1>
    </a>
    <a href="index.html">
      <div style="margin-top:10px;" class="page2">
        <h1><b>Choice 6</b></h1>
      </div>
    </a>
  </center>
  </div>
  <img id="next" style="margin-top: 8px; height: 60px; position: relative; left: 48%" src="http://i.imgur.com/yse3cEr.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://i.imgur.com/nDvQje1.png'" onmouseout="this.src='http://i.imgur.com/yse3cEr.png'">
  <img id="back" style="margin-top: 35px; height: 69px; position: relative; left: 48%; bottom: 1.7em" src="http://i.imgur.com/TVVVUju.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://i.imgur.com/lHpV00R.png'" onmouseout="this.src='http://i.imgur.com/TVVVUju.png'">
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place your anchors in a block element not in a block element.
Each anchor has been placed inside it's former child `.items`. Anchors are by default, inline and they do not obey left and right margins and width. If you don't want to move the anchors around, you can also do this:

```
a { display: block;} /* if you want them stacked /*
a { display: inline-block; } /* if you want them side by side */
```

I also replaced that ancient and deprecated element `<center>` with `<main>` and centered by this:

```
main { 
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".page2").hide();
  $("#back").hide();
  $("#next").click(function() {
    $(".items").hide();
    $(".page2").css({
      "width": "50%",
      "height": "50px",
      "background-color": "#2f8073",
      "border-radius": "5px",
      "border": "1px ridge #1c1c1c",
      "margin-bottom": "15px"
    });
    $(".page2").show();
    $("#next").hide();
    $("#back").show();
  });
  $("#back").click(function() {
    $(".page2").hide();
    $(".items").show();
    $("#back").hide();
    $("#next").show();
  });
  $(".page2").hover(function() {
    $(this).css({
      "background-color": "#2f8073",
      "border-radius": "5px",
      "border": "1px ridge #1c1c1c",
      "margin-bottom": "15px",
      "height": "52px",
      "width": "52%"
    });
  }, function() {
    $(this).css({
      "width": "50%",
      "height": "50px",
      "background-color": "#2f8073",
      "border-radius": "5px",
      "border": "1px ridge #1c1c1c",
      "margin-bottom": "15px"
    });
  });

});
```

```css
.items {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #2f8073;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px ridge #1c1c1c;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.page2 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #2f8073;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px ridge #1c1c1c;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 23px;
  color: black;
  font: arial;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.items:hover,
.page2:hover {
  width: 52%;
  height: 52px;
}
.items,
.page2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
/*main {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}*/
 
**EDIT:** I removed the `<main>` and put the `<center>` back, your layout is too complex. Just remember that `<center>` is not HTML5 it's HTML4 and it'll be gone when HTML4 is gone.
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
  <title>Menu</title>
</head>

<body>
  <center>

    <div style="margin-top:10px;" class="items">
      <a href="index.html"><h1><b>Choice 1</b></h1> </a> 
    </div>

    <div class="items">
      <a href="index.html">
        <h1><b>Choice 2</b></h1> 
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="items">
      <a href="index.html">
        <h1><b>Choice 3</b></h1> 
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="items">
      <a href="index.html">
        <h1><b>Choice 4</b></h1> 
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="items">
      <a href="index.html">
        <h1><b>Choice 5</b></h1>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div style="margin-top:10px;" class="page2">
      <a href="index.html">
        <h1><b>Choice 6</b></h1>
      </a>
    </div>

  </center>
  <img id="next" style="margin-top: 8px; height: 60px; position: relative; left: 48%" src="http://i.imgur.com/yse3cEr.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://i.imgur.com/nDvQje1.png'" onmouseout="this.src='http://i.imgur.com/yse3cEr.png'">
  <img id="back" style="margin-top: 35px; height: 69px; position: relative; left: 48%; bottom: 1.7em" src="http://i.imgur.com/TVVVUju.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://i.imgur.com/lHpV00R.png'" onmouseout="this.src='http://i.imgur.com/TVVVUju.png'">
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this part of your stylesheet:

```
    .items, .page2 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

}
```

change `display: flex;` to `display: inline-block;`.

Answer (score 0):

CSS change:

```
a{

    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 calc((100% - 300px)/2);//300px is size of button
    width: 300px;//300px is size of button
}

.items{
    width: inherit;
}
```